# How to modify the Map-Reduce execution order?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The original Map-Reduce execution chain is: `InputSplits-->Mapper--> [Sorting/Shuffling, etc]-->Reducer-->...`

Now I don't want the input splits to get to the Mappers first, but to go to some other new stage instead (we can call it Pre-Mapper for example, this class will be created by myself).

So the new order will be: `InputSplits -> Pre-Mapper->Mapper ->...`

I'm currently reading the source code. However, I still cannot find any clue (what classes I should touch).

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at chaining mappers: [ChainMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/chain/ChainMapper.html)

Comment: I never heard of this class. 
I will look deeper to see if it suitable for my needs. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

you can implement it use two stages MapReduce:

stage one:  Mapper -> Sorting/Shuffling -> Reducer[this reducer do nothing but write the data      directly form Mapper];

stage two: Mapreduce;

this stage one here is what you do in your Pre Mapper;

Comment: I think it's less efficient, the fact that you have a reducer that does nothing implies that you have a sort phase, which is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider overriding the [MapRunner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapRunner.html) class